# jQuery Mobile and Cordova (PhoneGap)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am writing a Cordova (PhoneGap) app and am at the moment just using jQuery. I was hesitant to use jQuery Mobile because I didn't think it allowed flexibility. I assumed the only way you could do things was its way. But I am considering using it because it will make many things easier for me. I just need to know I can do certain things:

- There are instances where JQM will be very nice for me, for example, switching between pages. However, there are some cases where I would like to manually slide between pages using the user's touch position instead of just a single slide animation. Is it possible to manually set the position of pages on the screen so that I can slide between them with my finger?
- I noticed that there are 2 JQM css files, one with their theme included and one without, just structure. What exactly are the differences between these two and how hard is it to implement a custom theme?
- I have a header that appears on some pages, but is only visible if you swipe down on the screen. Can I manually slide down the header from above the screen?

Also, if anyone has used Cordova (PhoneGap) and jQuery Mobile together, if you have any general tips or tricks to make the process faster for me that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Hm.. maybe google?

[Docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/phonegap.html)

[developing-mobile-applications-with-phonegap-and-jquery-mobile](http://pieterderycke.wordpress.com/2012/03/26/developing-mobile-applications-with-phonegap-and-jquery-mobile/)

[lessons-learned-from-phonegap-cordova-and-jquerymobile-on-android](http://blog.applegrew.com/2013/07/lessons-learned-from-phonegap-cordova-and-jquerymobile-on-android/)

Answer (score 2):

I've built a few apps with JQM now.

1. You can do that but you will need to write something custom. In version 1.40rc 1 there are some more touch based navigation controls. I suggest checking the documentation.
2. No difference really the one without the extra themes just doesnt have the b,c,d... themes. I tend to use the basic css structures and then build out my own custom ones on top of that. JQM recommends using a themes folder. I have found this a bit clunky in the past as it adds a lot of extra code. You can easily write your own css styles though. I typically have a jqm-custom.css that I include after the basic styles.
3. You can set a fixed header yes - I believe this is what you are asking. This support in rc1.4 is a lot better.
4. Do a search on google groups - for phonegap and jqm that's going to be your best bet - You will run into some oddities along the way.